# How to access image's matrix in matlab and scan it to find the specific pixel values?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i need to access image's matrix and scan it from top to bottom and left to right, because i need to make code for connected components labelling algorithm.But i dont know where to start from? because i dont know how to store matrix? as i am a newbie in matlab
 Loop can be run like

```
[rows columns] = size(img);

for a=1:1:rows
    for b=1:1:columns
```

but, i am not sure, if it is the correct way or not? as i need to access each pixel value and find specific value? how to write, if pixelvalue=1, add 1 to it?

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab you do not necessarily need to use loops to parse the values of a matrix. In this simple case you can use logical indexing (see different [indexing methods in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.fr/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)) to find specific values in your matrix and modify it.

For your special case you want to modify only pixels that have the value 1 and set this value to 2. It is simply written:

```
img(img==1)=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

read the file

```
I = imread('image.png');
```

If it's an RGB image, each pixel value (at `i` and `j`) could be accessed like:

```
r = I(i, j, 1);
g = I(i, j, 2);
b = I(i, j, 3);
```